# Span column in a multicols environment

Tags: multicol

I am using the `multicol` package to make a 2 columns based document but I want in a place to have just fusion these two columns, and then go back to the 2 columns but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a generalized version of Tom Bombadil's `\multicolinterrupt` macro: The current value of `\col@number` is saved before ending the `multicols` environment, and after typesetting the "interruption" text a new `multicols` environment with the same number of columns as the last one is started.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{tempcolnum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\multicolinterrupt}[1]{% Stuff to span both rows
\setcounter{tempcolnum}{\col@number}
\end{multicols}
#1%
\begin{multicols}{\value{tempcolnum}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\lipsum[1-2]
\multicolinterrupt{\textcolor{blue}{\lipsum[3-4]}}
\lipsum[5-6]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, I was wondering if the current column number was somehow accessible, but was, to be honest, too lazy to look it up :)

Answer (score 11):

Probably like this?

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\multicolinterrupt}[1]{% Stuff to span both rows
\end{multicols}
#1
\begin{multicols}{2}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\multicolinterrupt{\textcolor{blue}{\lipsum[3-4]}}
\lipsum[5-6]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]