# Span text across columns in multicol

Tags: memoir, two-column, multicol

I am writing a long document with memoir class and multicol package, mostly writing in 2 columns. I am trying to insert a framed text that spans across the two columns, but does not break the flow of text inside the columns. I can end the multicol, insert my framed text, and re-enter the multicol, but it breaks the flow of the text -- as in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59173/27424).

Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve: [image]

The text flows from 1's to 4's. The text of A's in the middle does not break the 1-4 flow. Is it possible to do so with multicol?

Comment: This is possible with [`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram). To be clear, The 1's flow from top-left to top-right, then bottom-left to bottom-right? And the 2's are fully independent from the entire text (just a bunch of "something else")?

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice to have 11111 222222 333333 444444 and AAAAA (for the added text, unless it's really a part of the main text).

Comment: Werner, actually, I want the text to flow from top-left to bottom left, then resume at top-right and end on bottom-right. Yes, the middle framed text is independent of the rest.
I edited the question so that it reflects more clearly what I am trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: This question no longer applies because the previous comment was edited to correct the issue.

Comment: Yes, I meant the A's are independent - I just corrected it.

Comment: Are you open to a [`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) solution?

Comment: @Werner sure, but does [flowfarm](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) work well with floats inside the columns? can I use mdframed with it? I'm worried about conflicts with other packages in my document. Nevertheless, I am open to [flowfarm](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram)  if it can solve my problem in a generic fashion. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please always supply a test document.

This is easy if you are prepared to add some space manually in the second column.

[image]

The wide text is just placed naturally in the first column together with some negative space so that it overprints the second column. then you just need to add a `\vspace` to leave a gap.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\def\a{1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 }
\def\b{2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 }
\def\c{3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 }
\def\d{4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 }
\def\aa{\a\a\par 11 11 \a\a\a\a\par 11 11 11\a 11 11 1 1 \a\a}
\def\bb{\b\b\b\par 22 22 222 \b\b\b\b\b\par\b\b\b\b\b\b}
\def\cc{\c\c\c\c\c\c\par\c 3\c3\c3\c3\c3\c3}
\def\dd{\d\d\d\d\par\d444\d}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\aa\a\aa\a

\smallskip
\noindent\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
\def\A{A A A A\dotfill A A A A\dotfill}
\A\A\A\A\A\A\A\A\A\A\A\A\A\A}}\kern-\textwidth
\par\smallskip

\bb\b\bb\b

\cc

\vspace{1.8cm}

\c\cc

\dd\dd\dd\dd\dd\dd

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: David, thank you for your answer! It's okay for a single case, although I had to spend some time to figure out the right spacing when the page is not full. I wish there was a generic way of doing it. Nevertheless, your answer will certainly help for now -thanks!