# Ending an environment in the 'before' of a new environment

Tags: page-breaking, multicol

I'm trying to create an environment that will close a `multicols` group, do a thing, then start a new `multicols`.

Something like

```
\newcount{\colcount}
\newenvironment{balancedbreak}{%
\let\colcount\col@number
\end{multicols}\newpage\begin{multicols}{\colcount}
}{
}
```

This does not work, I get the error message

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{balancedbreak} on input line 38 ended by \end{multicols}
```

**MWE**

This builds.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcount{\colcount}
\newenvironment{balancedbreak}{%
\let\colcount\col@number%
%\end{multicols}\newpage\begin{multicols}{\colcount}%
\newpage
}{%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\begin{balancedbreak}
\textbf{Testing here}
\end{balancedbreak}
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I get one long unbalanced column, then a new page and balanced columns. If I uncomment the line starting `\end{multicols}` in the new environment and comment out the next one I get the error message above.

I'm curious about the general case: "how do I end an environment in the 'before' section of a `\newenvironment`?

(My immediate need is "how can I better achieve the goal of ending a `multicols` page so it balances and move to the next page?". I could simply not do it at all the way I am now, but I'd like to use an environment for other reasons.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a whole lot easier to do this with a macro.  With an environment you have to keep track of `\@currenvir` and to be in the right group. The \endgroup and \begingroup are to terminate and restart the blanacedbreak environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\tracingmacros=1

\makeatletter
\newcount{\colcount}
\newenvironment{balancedbreak}{%
\global\colcount=\col@number% current value will otherwise be lost
\endgroup\endmulticols\newpage
\multicols\colcount\begingroup
\def\@currenvir{balancedbreak}%
}{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\begin{balancedbreak}
\textbf{Testing here}
\end{balancedbreak}
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I considered a macro (and found http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59166/span-column-in-a-multicols-environment), but I became interested in this as a general case problem. I have reasons (that I won't bore you with) for wanting to use an environment here... but I suppose if I'm messing with the native grouping aspects I'm not *really* using an environment, am I?

Comment: This does what I'd asked, so I'm selecting it as the answer. Turns I asked how to do a foolish thing and can't use it for my intended purpose, but this does do what I'd asked.

Answer (score 1):

Further research and experimentation show that the new environment is not just a 'wrapper for stuff', but actually has structural meaning (creates a implicit group). That is,

```
\newcount\colcount
\newenvironment{balancedbreak}{%
\let\colcount\col@number%
\end{multicols}\newpage\begin{multicols}{\colcount}%
}{%
}
```

acts something like

- `\begin{balancedbreak}`

  - `\begingroup`

    - `\let\colcount\col@number`
    - `\end{multicols}\newpage\begin{multicols}{\colcount}`

I'd thought -- incorrectly, it seems -- that the 'before' was something like a text substitution. I'd forgotten the implicit `begingroup`.

It turns out that using the definition above,

```
\balancedbreak
Some content goes here
\endbalancedbreak
```

Does appear to work.

Current working solution:

```
\newcount\colcount
\newenvironment{balancedbreak}{%
\ifnum\doublecol@number>\z@ % if multicol
  \let\colcount\col@number%
  \end{multicols}\newpage\begin{multicols}{\colcount}%
\else%
  \newpage%
\fi
}{%
}
```

This works if and only if there is no other `\begin{someenv}` between the `\begin{multicols}` and the `\balancedbreak`. There can be a `\begin{someenv} some stuff goes here \end{someenv}` without a problem, but this cannot happen 'inside' another environment or group.

This is way more brittle than really makes me happy, and I don't know that I'd recommend it as a general solution. That said, understanding how it works and why, I think I can live with it. I am, of course, open to other solutions.

Comment: I believe if you set the number of columns to 3 it will fail.  \begin{multicols}{0} defaults to 2 columns.  You also need \makeatletter ... \makeatother to use any macro name that includes @.

Comment: heh, I'd noticed that myself when I saw the error message. `\global\colcount=\col@number` solved that. And I'm doing this in a package, so the @ is just fine (in preamble it wouldn't be).